# Is it Possible to Load data to MongoDB Using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, ssis, etl

Is it Possible to Load data to MongoDB Using SSIS? If yes tools required to achieve? Does MongoDB Support all the SQL Operations?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it Possible to Load data to MongoDB Using SSIS? If yes tools required to achieve?

There are several ways to load data into MongoDB using SSIS:

#### 1. Using a Script Component as a Destination

The first approach is to use a Script Component as a destination. You should use the MongoDB .NET Driver to insert rows into the MongoDB database within the Script Component.

- [Data migration to NoSQL from Relational DB using MongoDB, MSSQL and SSIS 2012](https://rajendersehgal.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/data-migration-between-mssql-nosql/)
- [MongoDB for .NET Developers official course](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M220N/about)

#### 2. Using Third-party component

You can buy a MongoDB SSIS third-party component from the Visual Studio Marketplace:

- [ZappySys SSIS MongoDB Destination](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ZappySys.SSISMongoDBDestination)
- [CDATA SSIS Data Flow Source & Destination for MongoDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.SSISDataFlowSourceDestinationforMongoDB)

---

> Do MongoDB Support all the SQL Operations?

No, as MongoDB is a Not a relational database and it has its own query language MQL which is built using Javascript.

You can check the following article, where similar features are listed:

- [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

---

#### Update @ 2023-01-22

Recently, I published an article on MSSQLTips.com where I discussed the different methods to migrate data from SQL Server to MongoDB using SSIS.

- [Migrate Data from SQL Server to MongoDB using SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7520/export-data-from-sql-server-to-mongodb-using-ssis/?_utm_source=HadiFadlallah)